# Is there a problem with no-ip.com

Tags: wifi

Iv'e just managed to get a WIFI re connect script working and have been testing it by pulling the power on my router and re connecting it; sO far so good. It all seems to reconnect, but when I try and access the Apache server from my mobile phone, I get server not found!

It works from within my WIFI, but not from the net.

I haven't changed anything on my router, apart from rebooting it a few times

I found this [article](http://www.csoonline.com/article/2449501/business-continuity/microsofts-takedown-of-no-ip-pushes-innocents-into-the-crossfire.html) on the net and wondered if it's not the script but noip's DUC (dynamic update client) not working. I don't seem to be able to log in to noip.com either!

If NoIP is compromised/blocked by Microsoft, will things go back to normal, or do I have to search for an alternative free Dynamic update client.

Any ideas?

I don't think it's the script, as I can get access if I find out my external IP address, but hear it is anyway, just in case anyone can spot a reason why this may have upset my Apache server.

```
#!/bin/bash                                  


    LOGFILE=/var/log/wifitestlogfile.log 

    TESTIP=74.125.224.72                          

    ping -c4 ${TESTIP} > /dev/null 

    if [ $? != 0 ]                            
    then

            message="$(date) -- WiFi seems down, restarting - message from script  /usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_2.sh"
            echo >$LOGFILE # empties the file so just the last log is saved
            echo $message >>$LOGFILE

        ifdown --force wlan0                     
        ifup wlan0                               
    else       
            message="$(date) -- WiFi seems up - message from script  /usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_2.sh"
            echo >$LOGFILE # empties the file so just the last log is saved
            echo $message >>$LOGFILE

    fi
```

Comment: I set up a new DNS [this one](http://freedns.afraid.org/) and installed the [script](http://freedns.afraid.org/scripts/update.sh.txt) and bingo, I'm back within 10 min!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the microsoft takedown of the noip domains. If you are using noip you are probably SOL until after lawyers get involved. Probably easier to move to another free dns provider, just like the botnets will.

Comment: there's no need to move to another provider, as of July 2 2014 [there were alternate domains to use on no-ip](http://www.noip.com/blog/2014/07/02/message-ceo-dan-durrer/). As of July 3 2014 [service was restored to most of their free domains](http://www.noip.com/blog/2014/07/03/update-microsoft-takedown/).